# Cannot access to the second user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am learning Django 2.2 using chart js, I trying to display my user skill when changing the id in the URL. I have 2 users, it is working for the first but not the second.

Here is the error:

```
Profile matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/skills/2/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Profile matching query does not exist.
```

Here is my profile model, Profile => models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/img', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png'])], blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_created(self):
        return self.created.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.name, self.get_created)
```

Here is my Skills models, Skills => models.py

```
from django.db import models
from profiles.models import Profile
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
# Create your models here.


class Skill(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}-{}".format(self.user, self.name, self.score)
```

Here is my Skills url, Skills => urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import skill_view, UserChartView

app_name = 'skills'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', skill_view, name='my-skills'),
    path('<profile_id>/', UserChartView.as_view(), name='user-skills'),
    ]
```

Here is my user view,  Skills => views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Skill
from profiles.models import Profile
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


# Create your views here.


class UserChartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'skills/user_skills.html'

    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('profile_id')
        return pk

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserChartView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(name__id=self.get_object())
        qs = profile.skill_set.all()
        context["qs"] = qs
        return context
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should really look into custom user models instead of a separate Profile model.

Comment: Btw, your profile model, as is, allows multiple profiles per user (ForeignKey instead of OneToOneField). Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

```
query: name__id=self.get_object() to id=self.get_object()
```

Answer (score 0):

You here aim to access the profile for which the `User` object has as `id=2`, but since the name of the user model is `profile_id`, this is likely the primary key of the `Profile`.

I advise to use a `DetailView`, since this can already do most of the boilerplate logic. You can simply secify that the `pk_url_kwarg` is `'profile_id'` here:

```
from app.models import Profile
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class UserChartView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    pk_url_kwarg = 'profile_id'
    template_name = 'skills/user_skills.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['qs'] = self.object.skill_set.all()
        return context
```

Comment: I have this error : Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/skills/1/
Raised by: skills.views.UserChartView

Comment: @hugokis: well then there is no `Profile` with primary key `1`. Note that having two profiles does *not* mean that the primary keys are `1` and `2`. It is the database that is responsible to distribute primary keys.